# How can I add a WYSIWYG editor onto the custom Options text area (frontend) in Magento?

Tags: magento, wysiwyg, frontend

I am trying to add a wysiwyg edito to the custom options text areas in the frontend of Magento... This is so that customers can have the ability to change the font etc. Can you advise the best way to do this. I currently have the following code from NicEdit, however that overwrites the text box and therefore doesn't post to the shopping cart etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
nicEditors.editors.push(
    new nicEditor().panelInstance(
        document.getElementById('options_6_text')
    )
 );
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could try having this WYSIWYG editor on a dummy textarea and have some other javascript that copies the contents back across into the (hidden) options textarea.